# Pass FormDataCollection to backend from frontend in TS

Tags: c#, typescript, vue.js

I want to pass the data to backend as FormDataCollection but I keep getting null value
Backend part that waits for the data:

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(FormDataCollection formData)
        {
            try
            {
                var priceFileGeneratorModel =
                    System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode<PriceFileGeneratorModel>(formData.Get("settings"));
            [...]
```

And on the frontend part it generates the type of FormDataCollection formData as any[], so I try to do that like:

```
api.get([{settings: data.value}]
```

as data.value is type of PriceFileGeneratorModel, and settings is the key that I expect in backend in method formData.Get("settings")

But every time I try to pass it, the backend gets a null even if data.value is not a null

Comment: Don't use `FormDataCollection`. That's an obsolete class used in the discontinued ASP.NET Core 2.0 to hold FORM POST data. GET has no body to begin with. Query parameters are available as parameters in the action method. You can also use model binding, specifying a strongly typed parameter whose property names match the query parameter names

Comment: Where did this code come from?[.NET Core 2.0 reached End Of Life in October 2018](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core). It was never a long-term support version. .NET Core 2.1, the first long-term support version, didn't have FormDataCollection. This code is obsolete for over 4 years and that was already know back then. It was already known that applications would have to support .NET Core 2.1